# iOS 10 Firebase Notification not showing on background

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I´m having trouble on receiving push notifications (background) on a specific device running iOS 10. Other phones with iOS 9 are doing fine.

Although if I open the app the notification shows a banner that I implemented. Why does not show anything in background state?

Reading the firebase documentation something made me a little confused

According to a github firebase example on the following link https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/FCMSwift/AppDelegate.swift, there is a comment in the didReceiveRemoteNotification method that says:

> // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in
>   the background, // this callback will not be fired till the user taps
>   on the notification launching the application. // TODO: Handle data of
>   notification

So it my app is in background, does not apple do the whole thing to make that default iOS notification?
 Does the content_available value interfere on this? I also send notification and data values.

Here is an example of the JSON I send:

```
{
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high",
    "data": {
        "post_id": "...",
        "push_id": "..."
    },
    "notification": {
        "title": "...",
        "body": "..."
    },
    "registration_ids": ["xxxx"]
}
```

The expected behaviour would be:

1. App dead: the system will show the notification
2. App background: the system will show the notification and call the didReceiveRemoteNotification method.
3. App active: the system will NOT show de notification and call the didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Right?

Comment: have you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumptions are correct except for number 2. There are several cases where apple will not call didReceiveRemoteNotification you even if you set the content_avaialable.

1) Device has low battery and is in power saver mode

2) App has "background app refresh" disabled

3) Other undocumented scenarios where apple decides not to wake up your app. Apple reserves the right to not deliver notifications for performance reasons.

Having said that, if the user taps the notification you will always get the payload in didReceiveRemoteNotification.

Comment: Holy mother! I had disabled my background refresh for centuries, and forgot it... struggled with this issue a lot...